# different log file for master and beta mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design, log

Hi i am facing a problem while shipping my database log

I have three database server dev, beta and master 
and i maintain log files for dev on github
and every log file has a version given to it like (001 next would be 002 and so on)
and then i would merge my code on github from dev branch to beta branch , clone the code on beta deploy server run this log files on beta while deploying its build(then while deploying it checks for last updated .sql file and start deploying from next file), test it and if all ok 
then again
i would merge my code on github from beta branch to master branch, clone the code on master deploy server run this log files on master while deploying its build, test it and if all ok
that would be my final release
sample log file

```
          20140926.sql
          --add a stored procedure
          --update employee where id=10;
          --alter table .etc
```

but now i am facing a problem in this 
i have a table called as `employee`
and on this i need to have different changes
like example

```
          20140926.sql
          --update employee set name="beta" where id=10;--this should go in beta database only BUT NOT IN MASTER
          --update employee set name="master" where id=10;--this should go in MASTER database only BUT NOT IN BETA
          --update sometable set something='somevalue' where nothing='nothing';--but his update is common for both BETA and MASTER branch
```

but if now i commit it on dev and merge to beta and deploy on beta this the changes which should go ONLY on MASTER are going on BETA
and this is totally screwing my whole exsisting logic

Comment: I think you have same value in a row but different `Id` in `employee` table in `beta` and `master` database server.

Comment: yes right one same row would have different values on master and different value for beta

Comment: @vijayp any suggestion please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see one solution to this situation is to have multiple commit of the same file.

let say `20140926.sql` file  in this case, Now you have two changes one should go to `Beta` server and one to `Master` server.

You can have two seperate commit, changes that suppose to go to `Beta` in one commit and changes that is suppose to `Master` in other commit, with proper comment to indentify and versions incrementing count too can help.

Now while merge in `Beta` branch you can get the only version of commited for it and in `Master` the other corresponding version commited for it.

Comment: means is it like having to separate log files lets say `20140926-master.sql` and `20140926-beta.sql` and deploy respected file on respected DB server

Comment: No, I mean  github commits for the same file, For code push, you can choose 1 commit for beta and 1 commit for master, use merge the get these respective changes in each branch